# Circle shape drawable not rendering color on some devices

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I'm in trouble with a drawable in Android and after several days of intensive research, I've decided to ask you for help.

To fit my needs, I've created a drawable to use it in my XML layout in Android Studio (the file is called circle.xml) Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:innerRadius="0dp"
               android:shape="ring"
               android:thicknessRatio="2"
               android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#BABABE"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The color set here is generic but depends of the case I use the drawable.
Here is the `ConstraintLayout` I'm using:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout11"
                android:layout_width="71dp"
                android:layout_height="71dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:backgroundTint="#D95F2B"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I set a new color with the following attributes:

```
android:background="@drawable/circle"
android:backgroundTint="#D95F2B"
```

Setting the `background` attribute makes the circle appears in the `ConstraintLayout` and setting `backgroundTint` color makes the color of the circle change.

The problem is, on some devices, it works well, but on some other devices, the `backgroundTint` color is not applied and the circle keep only the color set in the drawable.

I know that I could set the color in my activity code but it's not really what I want to.

Any idea to fix it ? Feel free to ask me some questions if needed.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: **on some devices, it works well, but on some other devices, the `backgroundTint` color is not applied**.... Please remind devices, i.e API level, type etc..

Comment: Is the issue constrained to a specifc Android Version of the device?

Comment: It does not work on a device that is on API level 23 (Honor 5C), another on API level 24 (Sony). It works well on this same on a Samsung (API 26), Nexus 6P (API 22), Pixel 2 (API 26). The behavior is totally random.

Comment: why don't you set the `backgroundTint` color to the ` <solid android:color="#BABABE" `

Comment: Because I don't always use the same color. One component is red, another is blue, etc

Comment: Please post your ConstraintLayout

Comment: I edited my post with the code of the ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that the drawable work as should it be, thus the Issue is with `android:backgroundTint` .

Indeed this attribute work on API'S > 21, while you may face some weird behaviors with some-other phone types.

So if you need to have a *generic* circle to use it everywhere, there are some work around:

- Using the color directly in the drawable `<solid android:color="@color/your_color"/>` and it's seems that won't help in your case.
- Use `android:colorBackground` attribute instead of `backgroundTint`,
  And you set it in style i.e :

Style:

```
<style name="YourStyle" parent="YourParent">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/circle</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/your_color</item>
    </style>
```

The style will be used with your constraint layout.

- Using a wrapper view i.e:

Xml:-

```
<ConstraintLayout
android:background="@drawable/circle"

 <View
 android:background="@color/your_color"
 >
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I try to replace backgroundTint with android:backgroundColor, the compiler give me the error: attribute android:backgroundColor not found

Comment: @IbrahimAli Where is the style being used, please be more descriptive

Comment: I tried both the style method and the wrapper one, no one is working. It seems that colorBackground doesn't have any effect on the color.

Comment: @Vinestro Sorry for that, but at least Wrapper way, should work.